# How do I return null from using substring?

Tags: javascript

I created a function that searches for the first occurence of the character in the string pointed to by the argument. What do I need to add to my function to make my second console.log return null?

```js
function my_strchr(param_1, param_2){
    return param_1.substring(param_1.indexOf(param_2));
};

console.log(my_strchr("asdfasdf", "s"));
console.log(my_strchr("asdf", "g"));
```

Comment: I think `substring` is not the correct function for your case, you can try `includes` which returns `true` or `false`. E.g. `return param_1.includes(param_2)` will output `true || false`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you need that `substring` bit, and could work solely with `indexOf`. If `indexOf` is false, it will return `-1`. In your case, you want this return value to be `null`. You could achieve what you're after like this:

```js
function my_strchr(param_1, param_2) {
  const returnVal = param_1.indexOf(param_2);
  return returnVal > -1 ? returnVal : null; // override -1 with null
}

console.log(my_strchr("asdfasdf", "s"));
console.log(my_strchr("asdf", "g"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explaination and presentaion! A follow up question I have is, if I wanted to create a function that searches for the first occurrence of the character c (an unsigned char) in the string pointed to by the argument str. If the terminating null character is considered to be part of the string and I wanted it to return a pointer pointing to the last matching character, or null if no match was found. How would that code be put together?